# How to create Image gallery using ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to create a Gallery using `ViewPager` and thumbnails below the `ViewPager` view exactly explained in [this source code](https://github.com/DevExchanges/ImageGalleryWithViewPager).
But my problem is that, my class is a Fragment instead of Activity and the class extends `DialogFragment`. I am confused how to do this. I can't resolve this error:

> The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment

I know that i can't use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in Fragment but i cannot use `getFragmentManager(`) either.How to fix this? Somebody please help.

My Adapter class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Integer> images;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Integer> imagesList) {
        super(fm);
        this.images = imagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.getInstance(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }
}
```

Adapter instantiation:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), images);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: *in Fragment but i cannot use getFragmentManager() either*, why ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I meant, it is giving me error

Comment: how many classes do u have ?

Comment: In total? Or related to ViewPager?

Comment: @Jas did you solve your problem , as you said i used a fragment instead of an activity and i am not facing any issues, i am using `getChildFragmentManager()` inside `ViewPagerAdapter()`

Comment: I tried changing to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm, images);`
and i got this error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: I am positing the required files see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have done here is i have created a `DummyFragment` that extends `DialogFragment` and moved all code from `MainActivity` to that `Fragment`, you can check the files, the remaining files are same as in the Code link you gave

**MainActivity**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dummy);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, DummyFragment.newInstance()).commit();

}

}
```

**layout_dummy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

</FrameLayout>
```

**DummyFragment** // Your Dialog Fragment

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by Satyen on 11/16/15.
*/
public class DummyFragment extends DialogFragment {

View view;

private ArrayList<Integer> images;
private BitmapFactory.Options options;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private View btnNext, btnPrev;
private FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayout thumbnailsContainer;
private final static int[] resourceIDs = new int[]{R.mipmap.a, R.mipmap.b,
        R.mipmap.c, R.mipmap.d, R.mipmap.e, R.mipmap.f, R.mipmap.g};

public static DummyFragment newInstance() {
    DummyFragment dummyFragment = new DummyFragment();
    return dummyFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    images = new ArrayList<>();

    //find view by id
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    thumbnailsContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
    btnNext = view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    btnPrev = view.findViewById(R.id.prev);

    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(0));
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(1));

    setImagesData();

    // init viewpager adapter and attach
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    inflateThumbnails();
    return view;
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i > 0) {
                //next page
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            } else {
                //previous page
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

private void setImagesData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < resourceIDs.length; i++) {
        images.add(resourceIDs[i]);
    }
}

private void inflateThumbnails() {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        View imageLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_image, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_thumb);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(onChagePageClickListener(i));
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
        options.inDither = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images.get(i), options );
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //set to image view
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //add imageview
        thumbnailsContainer.addView(imageLayout);
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener onChagePageClickListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: @Jas did it help, or any issues you faced ?

Comment: I had some errors related to the import statements. I resolved them. But now, ViewPager is not showing any image. I'm checking that

Comment: I resolved it. Working great!! :) Thanks for your help dude :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for creating an indicator for viewPager that shows a small preview for each images in the viewPager with ability to delete item in real time.

It's nice to take a look at:
[ThumbIndicator](https://github.com/mahdimoqadasi/ThumbIndicator):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> my class is a Fragment instead of Activity and the class extends
>   DialogFragment. I am confused how to do this. I can't resolve this
>   error:

in this case you have to use `getFragmentManager()` directly. Android will return the support fragment manager if your Fragment is from the support package. In this case I think you probably want to use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: `The constructor ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, ArrayList<Integer>) is undefined`. This is the error. Please find the edited question also

Comment: where are you trying to instantiate the adapter ? Post that code

Comment: I see. Check the imports of the class where you are instantiating the adapter. They have to be from the support package.

Comment: `DialogFragment` also from support package??

Comment: everything has to be from the support package

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one option. Not sure which exactly will be best for your case.

1). (Probably what you need) `fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` will return nested fragment manager for your fragment. Its usually used for adding/replacing fragments to other fragments, so paging is similar case.

2) `getActivity().getFragmentManager() / getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` will return fragment manager of `Activity` (same used for adding/replacing fragment directly on `activity` layout

Comment: `fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` still giving same error.

Comment: You are using `android.app.Fragment` or support ones?

Comment: I'm using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` currently. `android.app.Fragment` isn't working either

Comment: So... support fragment have this method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager(), check if your adapter's constructor's parameter is support v4 fragment manager. I'll be glad if you paste exact error message

Comment: Please find the edited question. I've added my adapter class.